# Elasticsearch: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Self-suppression not permitted when running on docker container

Tags: java, docker, elasticsearch

i have two docker containers one is running an elasticsearch and another one is running my app which is using elasticsearch running in the container my app is working fine when both the elasticsearcj and my app working outside of docker in my machine 
when i run both on docker i am getting `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Self-suppression not permitted`
 exception

here is how i am doing
running ES on docker container

```
docker run --network=mynetwork -p 9200:9200 -p 9300:9300 --name docker-es -e "discovery.type=single-node" -e "cluster.name=my-cluster" elasticsearch:7.1.0
```

here is how i am running myapp container

```
docker run --network=mynetwork myapp
```

when i am trying to create a mapping for es doc i am getting this exception

```
12:04:19.347 11090 [run-main-0] HazelcastServer INFO - Starting ElasticSearch client and node in hazelcast Server on org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient@c7484d8
12:04:19.377 11120 [pool-12-thread-1] PurchasingOrPledgeDetailsESIndexAndMappingMapping$ ERROR - index purchasingorpledgedetailsis not created with an exception {}
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:779)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.DefaultConnectingIOReactor.processEvent(DefaultConnectingIOReactor.java:171)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.DefaultConnectingIOReactor.processEvents(DefaultConnectingIOReactor.java:145)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.execute(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:351)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.conn.PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager.execute(PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager.java:221)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.CloseableHttpAsyncClientBase$1.run(CloseableHttpAsyncClientBase.java:64)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Aug 22, 2019 12:04:19 PM org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.InternalHttpAsyncClient run
SEVERE: I/O reactor terminated abnormally
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Self-suppression not permitted
    at java.base/java.lang.Throwable.addSuppressed(Throwable.java:1025)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.addSuppressedException(RestClient.java:489)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.access$1400(RestClient.java:95)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient$FailureTrackingResponseListener.trackFailure(RestClient.java:587)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient$FailureTrackingResponseListener.onDefinitiveFailure(RestClient.java:579)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient$1.failed(RestClient.java:333)
    at org.apache.http.concurrent.BasicFuture.failed(BasicFuture.java:137)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.DefaultClientExchangeHandlerImpl.executionFailed(DefaultClientExchangeHandlerImpl.java:101)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.AbstractClientExchangeHandler.failed(AbstractClientExchangeHandler.java:426)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.AbstractClientExchangeHandler.connectionRequestFailed(AbstractClientExchangeHandler.java:348)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.AbstractClientExchangeHandler.access$100(AbstractClientExchangeHandler.java:62)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.AbstractClientExchangeHandler$1.failed(AbstractClientExchangeHandler.java:392)
    at org.apache.http.concurrent.BasicFuture.failed(BasicFuture.java:137)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.conn.PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager$1.failed(PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager.java:316)
    at org.apache.http.concurrent.BasicFuture.failed(BasicFuture.java:137)
    at org.apache.http.nio.pool.RouteSpecificPool.failed(RouteSpecificPool.java:162)
    at org.apache.http.nio.pool.AbstractNIOConnPool.requestFailed(AbstractNIOConnPool.java:609)
    at org.apache.http.nio.pool.AbstractNIOConnPool$InternalSessionRequestCallback.failed(AbstractNIOConnPool.java:889)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.SessionRequestImpl.failed(SessionRequestImpl.java:160)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.DefaultConnectingIOReactor.processEvent(DefaultConnectingIOReactor.java:173)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.DefaultConnectingIOReactor.processEvents(DefaultConnectingIOReactor.java:145)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.execute(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:351)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.conn.PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager.execute(PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager.java:221)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.CloseableHttpAsyncClientBase$1.run(CloseableHttpAsyncClientBase.java:64)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:779)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.DefaultConnectingIOReactor.processEvent(DefaultConnectingIOReactor.java:171)
    ... 5 more
```

can anyone please guide me what is wrong here?

Comment: The actual error is `Connection refused`. Assuming you connect from the Java app to `docker-es` (the name of the container), check if elasticsearch can be accessed from outside machine (binds other than to `localhost`).